# Bootstrap 3: Remove bottom margin from the columns at the bottom of row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a grid with multiple columns. All columns are in one row and the number of columns may vary.

Since I needed some vertical space between columns, I added margin-bottom on columns.

However, I want equal space **between wrapper and the columns** so I need to remove margin-bottom on last few columns in the row.

```
See sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/aucovic/rhhyu6h2/6/
```

How would I dynamically remove bottom-margin on those last few columns?

```
<style>
.wrapper {
  background:#000;
  padding:10px;
}

.box {
  background: #fff;
}

.mb {  
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
</style>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mb">
      <div class="box">
        Box 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mb">
      <div class="box">
        Box 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mb">
      <div class="box">
        Box 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mb">
      <div class="box">
        Box 4
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 mb">
      <div class="box">
        Box 5
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code direct in your question.

Comment: Why not add the margin go the `box` and equalize with the `wrapper` padding: http://www.bootply.com/gAVN0Qi3HT

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't change the number of columns, nth child selectors could help:

```
//mobile and tablet view
@media(max-width:992px) {
    .mb:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
        margin-bottom:0px; 
    }
}
//wider views
@media(min-width:993px) {
    .mb:nth-last-child(-n+3) {
        margin-bottom:0px; 
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated your fiddled to show this in effect: https://jsfiddle.net/rhhyu6h2/8/

Again, only for this specific layout.  For variable columns layouts, you have to solve in a wrapper or through JS.

EDIT2: from reading your other comments, you could use a wrapper adjustment class on selective rows:  https://jsfiddle.net/rhhyu6h2/9/
This doesn't require any new HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case you want the wrapper to have some padding, a super quick-fix would be to set the bottom padding to be equal (initial padding - margin bottom of columns). On your example it's just gonna be `padding-bottom: 0` for your wrapper. This is definitely not an ultimate fix, but is super simple and works in described case.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kLr8sog6/

Comment: Thx Gleb, that's what I ve already done, but I m not happy with that solution because in some cases I need that padding at the bottom :/

Comment: ok, then you can give padding to the the column container and negative margin to the row, like here: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkost/kLr8sog6/2/

Comment: Need that margin at the row too :/

Comment: Ok, why don't you add a row wrapper and add all the margins you need to it? https://jsfiddle.net/glebkost/kLr8sog6/3/

Answer (score 0):

@Antonio, in order to remove the bottom-margin dynamically you gotta use jQuery/JavaScript. On appropriate event add the class which has margin-bottom:0px.

Example:

**CSS Code:**

```
.removeBottomPadding{
margin-bottom:0px !important; 
}
```

**JavaScript Code:** [Ensure to add an id to the wrapper]

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById('wrapper').className = 'removeBottomPadding';
};
```

**OR**

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(function() {
$('.wrapper').addClass('removeBottomPadding');
});
```

That's all.

Good luck & hope that helps.